# Как запускать проекты в Sublime через командную строку

Tags: git, github, sublime-text-3

Разбираюсь с git, застопился на вопросе а как собственно открыть папку проекта в редакторе Sublime Text?

Comment: А зачем через командную строку?

Comment: Нужно открыть его так чтобы проект интегрировался с github, через приложение github desktop можно запустить, а вот вопрос можно ли также через командную строку запустить?

Comment: Синхронизация вашего локального проекта с удалённым репозиторием на github совершенно не зависит от способа открытия проекта в Sublime. Я это обычно делаю из самого редактора через File/Open, но наверняка есть и другие способы

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы открыть проект в Sublime на Windows, нужно:

- зайти в `Мой компьютер > Свойства > Доп параметры > Переменные среды`
- создать переменную среды для `username` (у меня whuser)

  ```
  имя       SUBLIME 
  значение  C:\Users\whuser\Downloads\Sublime Text Build 3126 (путь к редактору)
  ```
- добавить её к `PATH`

  ```
  имя       PATH 
  значение  C:\Users\whuser\AppData\Roaming\npm;%SUBLIME%
  ```

Теперь через gitbash с рабочего стола нужно выполнить `subl D:web/Work_project` - указанный проект будет открыт в редакторе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее можно почитать в [гайде](https://scotch.io/tutorials/open-sublime-text-from-the-command-line-using-subl-exe-windows) (на английском)